# При вызове return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id); Выдает ошибку Class 'League\Flysystem\Cached\Storage\AbstractCache' not found

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel, framework, site

Всем привет! Весь интернет перерыл не могу найти решение данной проблемы
У меня проект на laravel 5.6 сервер NGINX , хочу сделать чтоб было видно когда пользователь зашел online , когда не в сети естественно offline. Создал middleware с названием UserActivity :

class UserActivity
{

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5);
        Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

}

прописал его в `Kernel`:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\UserActivity::class,
```

После этого как нужно в моделе Users прописал метод:

```
public function isOnline()

{
    return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
}
```

При вызове его в шаблоне blade:

```
@foreach($users as $item)
    @if($item->isOnline())
           <li class="media"><img class="media-object" src="../assets/img/prof/prof3.jpg" width="35" height="35" alt="...">
           <i class="online dot"></i>
               <div class="media-body">
                   <h5 class="media-heading">{{ $item->name }}</h5>
                   <div class="media-heading-sub"></div>
                  </div>
           </li>
        @endif
      @endforeach
```

Выдает ошибку

> **Class** 'League\Flysystem\Cached\Storage\AbstractCache' not found.

Я лез внутрь класса `Cache` и обнаружил что он наследуется от `AbstractCache`, но этого абстрактного класса нет в проекте, что делать помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы видать не тот класс берете Illuminate\Support\Facade\Cache - у вас этот Cache

Comment: Я решил эту проблему подключив в модели users все пространство имен - use Cache